# WooCommerce: Increase cart item quantity if the product already exist in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I want to increase the quantity of a product on the cart page of WooCommerce if the product already exists on the cart.

I tried this piece of code

```
if ( 'same_product_added_to_cart' === $customer_gets_as_free ) {
   foreach ( $main_product_id as $main_product_single ) {
        $main_product_single = intval( $main_product_single );
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] === $main_product_single ) {
        // Get the current quantity
        $current_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        // Increase the quantity by one
        $new_quantity = $current_quantity + 1;

        // Update the cart with the new quantity
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $new_quantity );

        break; // Exit the loop since we have found our product
       }
       }
   }
}
```

It did not work, instead, it triggered an infinite amount of loops giving an error. What am I doing wrong here. and also the `add_to_cart()` function gives an error of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, WooCommerce does that by itself if there is no different custom cart item data added to the cart item on add to cart.

There are mistakes and missing steps in your code.

Here is the way to merge duplicated products (cart items):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'merge_duplicated_products_in_cart');
function merge_duplicated_products_in_cart( $cart ) {
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    $items_data = $item_update = []; // initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        $quantity   = $cart_item['quantity'];

        // Check if the product exists
        if( in_array($product_id, array_keys($items_data)) ) {
            // Same product found
            $item_update['item_qty'] = $items_data[$product_id]['qty'] + $quantity; // Set cumulated quantities
            $item_update['item_key'] = $items_data[$product_id]['key']; // Add first product item key
            $item_update['item_remove'] = $cart_item_key; // Add current item key (product to be removed)
            break; // Stop the loop
        } 
        // Add product_id, cart item key and item quantity to the array (for each item)
        else {
            $items_data[$product_id] = array(
                'key' => $cart_item_key,
                'qty' => $quantity
            );
        }
    }
    unset($items_data); // delete the variable

    if ( ! empty($item_update) ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item($item_update['item_remove']); // remove last item (same product)
        $cart->set_quantity($item_update['item_key'], $item_update['item_qty']); // Update quantity on first item(same product)
        unset($item_update); // delete the variable
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

**Addition** *(based on the OP comment)*:

The following will target specific defined product(s). If a specific product is already in cart, increase the quantity by one *(define your product(s) ID(s) below)*:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'merge_duplicated_products_in_cart');
function merge_duplicated_products_in_cart( $cart ) {
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    $targeted_product_ids = array(18); // <== HERE set your(s) targeted product(s) ID(s)

    $items_data = $item_update = []; // initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

        // Look for specific products only
        if ( in_array($product_id, $targeted_product_ids) ) {
            $quantity   = $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Check if the product is already in cart
            if( in_array($product_id, array_keys($items_data)) ) {
                // Same product found
                $item_update['item_qty'] = $items_data[$product_id]['qty'] + 1; // ADD ONE TO THE QUANTITY
                $item_update['item_key'] = $items_data[$product_id]['key']; // Add first product item key
                $item_update['item_remove'] = $cart_item_key; // Add current item key (product to be removed)
                break; // Stop the loop
            } 
            // Add product_id, cart item key and item quantity to the array (for SPECIFIC items only)
            else {
                $items_data[$product_id] = array(
                    'key' => $cart_item_key,
                    'qty' => $quantity
                );
            }
        }
    }
    unset($items_data); // delete the variable

    if ( ! empty($item_update) ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item($item_update['item_remove']); // remove last item (same product)
        $cart->set_quantity($item_update['item_key'], $item_update['item_qty']); // Update quantity on first item(same product)
        unset($item_update); // delete the variable
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Actually, to be more precise I was searching for a different thing. I have id of a particular product and I want to search that if that product is added in the cart page of Woocommerce. if that product exists on the cart page I want to increase its quantity by 1. That means if that product quantity is already 2 then make it three.

Comment: Actually I did not get this part. where are you getting this $items_data? I have used your code and nothing happens. Though from your code I have learned few things. Could you please explain why you have used this array_keys($items_data))?

Comment: You have done more than enough, I will try to find a way. I'm accepting your answer as the solution.